# SWR vs Isomorphic-unfetch for data fetch Next.Js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, isomorphic-fetch-api

While reading the Next.Js tutorial in the Routing API I learned about fetching data with these 2 libs.

The fetch object from Isomorphic-unfetch, is used within the getInitialProps async function to call an external API. Then in the Route API part, the SWR along with the { useRouter } from 'next/router; shapes the call to an internal API developed within the same Next.Js server with a lot of flexibility to query the req params.

Other than these 2 aspects, what other differences are between these 2 approaches?

Answer (score 9):

[`isomorphic-unfetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-unfetch) allows you to make `fetch` calls on both the client *and* the server, which is why it's shown in examples that use `getInitialProps`.

Generally speaking, you [fetch data](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) on the server using `getInitialProps`. This will be **blocking** – meaning the markup will not be returned until your data has been fetched. Consider a product page for an e-commerce site. It's important that we return the product name, price, and other information from the server and not on the client-side.

[SWR](https://swr.now.sh/) is similar, but a bit different. It first returns the data from cache (stale), then sends the fetch request (revalidate), and finally comes with the up-to-date data again. A real-world example of where you'd use something like SWR is on a dashboard page. You don't want to fetch *all* the data in `getInitialProps` in a blocking manner, so you render out the dashboard "shell" in a loading state, and then use SWR to fetch the data client side. You can view an example of this [here](https://leerob.io/dashboard).

---

Source - Creator of [Mastering Next.js](https://masteringnextjs.com/)

Comment: **Update:** With Next.js 9.4, `fetch` is polyfilled––removing the need for `isomorphic-unfetch` as a dependency.